# What do I need to build to directly access the InfiniBand HCA ports and inject an IPoIB frame bits?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, infiniband

I would like to retrieve the IPoIB frame bits for all the IPoIB frames on the fabric no matter if they are destined (LID + QPN level) for my machine or not.

Also, I should be able to re-inject the modified IPoIB frames directly to the InfiniBand HCA ports from the linux Kernel.

```
The logic for that has to be at the kernel level.
```

So in order to achieve this do I need to build a **separate kernel module** or **IPoIB driver** or **IPoIB network interface**

*Note: I have just started learning Linux kernel module development for my project. I'm sorry if it is not the appropriate place to post this question.*

Comment: How are you planning to make the network redirect all the traffic to your machine?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have a big problem receiving IPoIB packets not destined for your machine.  The fabric forwards packets based on the destination LID, and if the LID is not associated with your local port, you won't receive the packet.